# Problem fetching sharepoint sites after upgrading the Microsoft.Graph Nuget package to version 5

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I was using Microsoft.Graph Nuget package version 4.48.0 before the upgrade. I used the following code to retrieve all the sharepoint sites:

```
List<QueryOption> queryOptions = new()
{
    new QueryOption("search", "*")
};

var sites = await graphClient.Sites.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
```

Everything worked without problems. The call retrieved all the sharepoint sites that I have access to.

After upgrading to version 5 and using the instructions from Microsoft's website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list, the code I use is as follows:

```
var sites = await graphClient.Sites.GetAsync();
```

This call returns 0 sites.

In both cases I use the correct access token to create graphClient. I guess that query options should be added somehow, but the documentation is quite incomplete and all my attempts to do so have failed.

I know that the sites can be fetched using the standard HttpClient and the command "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*", but I would like to know how to do this using SDK.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
var result = await graphClient.Sites.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Search = "*";
});
```

`GetAsync` method accepts [requestConfiguration](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#query-parameter-options) where you specify query for filtering, searching, etc.

There is a known [bug](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1884) for searching sites with `*` character.

According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1826#issuecomment-1531405983) the workaround should

```
var requestInformation = graphClient.Sites.ToGetRequestInformation();
requestInformation.UrlTemplate = requestInformation.UrlTemplate.Replace("%24search", "search");
requestInformation.QueryParameters.Add("search", "*");
var sites = await graphClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync<SiteCollectionResponse>(requestInformation, SiteCollectionResponse.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);
```

Comment: The workaround method really helped. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, the [code snippet](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1826#issuecomment-1531405983) provided by @andrueastman and @user2250152 works fine:

[image]